# Interromper contagem do for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu posso interromper a contagem do FOR no Jquery?
Por exemplo:

Esse código:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

Mostrará o resultado:

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 4
```

Mas eu gostaria de exibir 5 resultados e não 4.
Como eu faço para o FOR não fazer o incremento ++?
Já tentei fazer assim:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { i--; continue; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

Mas por algum motivo ele trava a tela e no servidor dá erro 503 o que significa que está consumindo muito processamento.

Comment: Joga um break em vez de continue

Comment: Seu servidor é Node?

Comment: Se eu jogar um break ele para o loop de vez, aí só teremos o resultado até o "The number is 2"

Comment: Não é Node Leonardo

Comment: De um exemplo de como seria o resultado que você espera obter.

Comment: Qual é o servidor? pq javascript não causa 503 no servidor, ele é processado no navegador.

Comment: O break irá fazer ele interromper por completo o for... ele não vai passar pra próxima repetição, irá sair e continuar o fluxo do código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o seu código está entrando em loop, já que quando você tem `i=3`  você decrementa ele e o `continue` faz ele ir para o próximo laço do for, onde ele passa a valer 3 novamente, e assim entra em loop.
Uma alternativa seria fazer o `for` correr até o `i` ser menor ou igual a 5:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //alterado
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Interessante esta observação do Lucas.

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas. Exatamente isso! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de fazer o que quer é contar a quantidade de elementos que já escreveu na tela.
Apesar de ser um pouco mais extenso é mais genérico e vai funcionar mesmo se quiser ignorar vários elementos.

Exemplo:

```js
let text = "";

for (let i = 0, escritos = 0; escritos < 5; i++) { //variavel escritos termina em 5
    if (i === 3) { continue; }
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    escritos++; //conta apenas os que foram escritos na tela
}

document.write(text);
```

Assim o valor de paragem não depende de cálculos que tenha de fazer para saber onde terminar o `for`, e passa a ser a quantidade que quer mostrar na tela.

Imagine que queria mostrar 15 elementos e saltar cada múltiplo de 3:

```js
let text = "";

for (let i = 0, escritos = 0; escritos < 15; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) { continue; }
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    escritos++;
}

document.write(text);
```

Note que em ambos os casos declarei a variável `i` no `for`, que é algo que não tinha feito e lhe pode gerar problemas, pois ela vira global. **Declare sempre as variáveis que utiliza**.